# Compare types of keys for SortedDictionary

Tags: c#, types, dictionary, comparator

I want to write a custom comparer for a `SortedDictionary`, where keys are sorted based on their type. Is this possible?

```
public class StateBase
{
    // This is a base class I have to inherit from
}

SortedDictionary<StateBase, int> _stateDictionary =
    new SortedDictionary<StateBase, int>(new StateComparer());

class StateComparer : IComparer<StateBase>
{
    public int Compare(StateBase a, StateBase b)
    {
        // I'd like to sort these based on their type
        // I don't particularly care what order they are in, I just want them
        // to be sorted.
    }
}
```

Comment: The keys will all be of the same type. Can you please clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can. If your comparer implements [`IComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf.aspx), it can be passed to a new `SortedDictionary` instance by the corresponding [constructor overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a045f865.aspx).

The `Compare` method then somehow decides what item is greater or lower. It is the place where you can implement your compare-by-type logic.

Here is an example to compare `Type` instances based on their name:

```
public class TypeComparer : IComparer<Type>
{
    public int Compare(Type x, Type y)
    {
        if(x != null && y != null)
            return x.FullName.CompareTo(y.FullName);
        else if(x != null)
            return x.FullName.CompareTo(null);
        else if(y != null)
            return y.FullName.CompareTo(null);
        else
            return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was wondering if there is a language defined way of ordering `Type` objects. The ordering can be something completely arbitrary.

Comment: I do not know, to be honest. It does not implement `IComparable`, however. You may use their name, for instance. I'll add an example to the post.

Comment: Ah, right. The name is a perfect solution! Please add it as an edit to your answer so I can accept it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Sure, why not? Note that we must be talking about reference-types for this to apply, so something like:

```
public class TypeComparer<T> : IComparer<T>, IEqualityComparer<T> where T : class
{
    public static readonly TypeComparer<T> Singleton= new TypeComparer<T>();
    private TypeComparer(){}
    bool IEqualityComparer<T>.Equals(T x, T y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
        if (x == null || y == null) return false;
        Type xType = x.GetType(), yType = y.GetType();
        return xType == yType && EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(x, y);
    }
    int IEqualityComparer<T>.GetHashCode(T x)
    {
        if (x == null) return 0;
        return -17*x.GetType().GetHashCode() + x.GetHashCode();
    }
    int IComparer<T>.Compare(T x, T y)
    {
        if(x==null) return y == null ? 0 : -1;
        if (y == null) return 1;

        Type xType = x.GetType(), yType = y.GetType();
        int delta = xType == yType ? 0 : string.Compare(
               xType.FullName, yType.FullName);
        if (delta == 0) delta = Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(x, y);
        return delta;
    }
}
```